# Vault token that does not expire

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I am using Vault Kubernetes auth method for authenticate services against Vault and I wonder if I can generate a token with this auth method which does not expire.

Comment: Only root token, Every non-root token has a time-to-live (TTL). read more [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/tokens)

Comment: As a workaround the TTL can be [renewed](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/tokens#renew-service-tokens), if the token is renewable.